# If $A,B \in \Bbb R ^{n \times n}$ have same $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, $AB=BA$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> If $A,B \in \Bbb R ^{n  \times n}$ have same $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, $AB=BA$.

I know that $A,B$ are similar to the same diagonal matrix so they are similar, but how is that help to prove? Maybe the statment is not right?

Comment: They're not actually similar to the same diagonal matrix; that would amount to having the same *eigenvalues*. These matrices have the same *eigenvectors*, so $A=V D_1 V^{-1}$ and $B=V D_2 V^{-1}$ are their eigendecompositions. Can you show these commute?

Comment: Thanks, I thought about the eigenvalues, and not about the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $a$, and of $B$ with eigenvalue $b$. Then
$$ (AB-BA)v = A(bv)-B(av) = b(Av)-a(Bv) = bav-abv=(ba-ab)v = 0. $$
This is true of any joint eigenvectors. Further, $(AB-BA)$ is a linear operator, so it is also zero on any linear combination of these eigenvectors. Since you have $n$ linearly independent (eigen)vectors $v_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, they form a basis. Hence and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ lies in their span, $x=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i$, so
$$ (AB-BA)x = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i (AB-BA) v_i = 0, $$
so $AB-BA$ is the matrix corresponding to the zero map, i.e. it is zero and $AB=BA$.

Answer (score 3):

If the eigenvalues are linearly independent, they form a base of $\Bbb R^n$. Their image also completely fixes the actions of $A$ and $B$, so you just need to check that each of the eigenvectors is mapped to the same image by $AB$ and $BA$, but this is trivial.

Comment: This is certainly a valid answer, but probably too subtle to grasp for someone just learning linear algebra for the first time.

Comment: What does it mean "completely fixes the actions of $A$ and $B$"?

Comment: minor typo: eigenvectors

Comment: @user3697301 if you know all eigenvalues and eigenvectors you know what the (linear) maps $AB$ and $BA$ are on a basis. By linearity, from this, you can calculate the value of $ABv$ or $BAv$ for any $v$ by writing $v$ as a linear combination of the eigenvectors (just like Chappers did).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I think I got your point, but I disagree.